# How do I make a toggle button affect a user script (cmix) in Xcode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, xcode4.3

I am building a simple step sequencer in IRTcmix (version of RTcmix for the iphone/ipad), using UI Buttons to control which notes are on or off in the sequence.

I have been working with a set of RTcmix examples of other apps, and trying to piece my own together, but i'm unsure how to change values of a variable within the .sco (score file) with a toggle-style UIButton.

Here are some snippets from a working RTcmix App:

From the RTcmix manager .h:

```
@interface RTcmixManager : RTcmixPlayer {
RTcmixScore     *polyScore;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   RTcmixScore     *polyScore;

- (void)noteOn:(int)note;
- (void)noteOff:(int)note;

@end
```

and the RTcmix manager .m

```
- (void)noteOn:(int)note {
[polyScore.mainScoreParameters replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:note]];
[polyScore.mainScoreParameters replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[self parseScoreWithRTcmixScore:polyScore];
polyScore.setupIsActive = YES;
}

- (void)noteOff:(int)note {
    [polyScore.mainScoreParameters replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:note]];
    [polyScore.mainScoreParameters replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
    [self parseScoreWithRTcmixScore:polyScore];
}
```

the viewcontroller .h:

```
@interface RTPolyphonyViewController : UIViewController {
RTcmixManager       *rtcmixManager;
}

- (IBAction)keyDown:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)keyUp:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

viewcontroller .m:

```
- (IBAction)keyDown:(UIButton *)sender {
[rtcmixManager noteOn:sender.tag]; 
}

- (IBAction)keyUp:(UIButton *)sender {
    [rtcmixManager noteOff:sender.tag]; 
}
```

and a snippet from the .sco file (the "%@" is the variables changed by user input):

```
NoteNumber = %@
NoteVelocity = %@

alreadySounding = note_exists(oscNotes[NoteNumber])
MAXMESSAGE(0, alreadySounding)
```

I am very new to objective C and xcode, I was wondering how to make a UI button toggle between two values in the score file (acting like a switch) for example, a button when toggled making the value of NoteNumber(in the score file) set to 1, while the value is 0 when toggled off. Because I am a beginner with Xcode(and objective C), I'm not sure about the proper syntax for making a button able to be toggled on and off, and i am also not sure how to connect said button with my .sco file, as much as I look at the sample code, I cannot seem to figure out how they all connect.